# Effect of ethanol added petrol on vintage cast iron engine bikes

Tags: engine, fuel-additives, alternative-fuels

I own a 1993 Royal Enfield Bullet 350 Classic. Recently my city switched to 10% ethanol added petrol from the earlier used pure petrol. I very rarely use the bike; approximately one time in every two months. I have searched on the internet and also read few stackexchange posts related to this but all of them were about new alloy engines. Will this new fuel cause any harm to the engine?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it might.**

There are two types of harm the fuel could cause:

- Ethanol attacking fuel hoses not designed for ethanol
- Gasoline being typically optimized for using quickly, not for 2-month storage (although storing it for 2 months is not as bad as, say for 1 year)

I would advise you to find out if "small-engine gasoline" is available where you live. It has been optimized to burn cleaner, and it as far as I know doesn't have any ethanol. Furthermore, its shelf life is much, much longer than that of regular gasoline.

Where I live, [small-engine gasoline](https://www.neste.com/benefits-small-engine-gasoline) is available widely, obviously at a higher cost than regular gasoline.

Comment: Alcohol free gas pumps are around depending on where you live.  You can check puregas.org if you're in North America.  Hardware stores and big box stores sell small engine gas.  It's expensive but worth it, especially for gas that will sit in your tank for long periods of time, but you should get in the habit of draining your carburetor float bowl and possibly your gas tank if your bike is going to sit for more than a week or two.  I have a bike with a fiberglass tank that ethanol will dissolve.  I avoid using gasahol although I don't worry as much about it in the middle of a long trip.